# ComboBox, very new to WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox bound to a collection of objects.  The objects have property boolean IsSelected which specifies if the object is currently selected to show in ComboBox text area.

In order to make it use the IsSelected boolean property to show default item in ComboBox, I added a ValueConverter class like below.

```
 public class SelectedItemConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value is IEnumerable<Car>)
            {
                return ((IEnumerable<Car>)value).Where(n => n.IsSelected).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value is Car)
            {
                return value;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My ComboBox is in a UserContrl and its xaml is:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CarsList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CarsList, Converter={StaticResource selectedItemConverter}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
</ComboBox>
```

I am using SelectedItem because my Car object has IsSelected which is boolean and it represents whether the Car is visible in ComboBox text area.  For that reason, I have the ValueConverter above to use that boolean to properly return object.

This works well and when ComboBox loads, the object that has IsSelected=True will show in ComboBox text area.  However, if I expand dropdown and select another object, that object will show but ComboBox gets a red border which as far as I know means that there is some validation problem.

How do I fix this?

I have seen many examples but none of them are addressing the issue where a boolean property IsSelected is used to determine which object to show in ComboBox.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Probably the problem is `ConvertBack` function, it should return `IEnumerable<Car> CarsList`. Anyway I think you should rethink abount binding to `SelectedItem` using that way.

Comment: You are correct, the ConvertBack is returning Car instance and not CarList instance.  But the problem is that I dont have CarList instance as it is not passed into the ConvertBack.  So not sure how to get it to return it.

Comment: I think @Bolu suggested good way how to change binding. Else you can try to pass `CarList` as a `ConverterParameter` (if `CarList` collection never changes you can define it in xaml like resource), but this is weird complicated way.

Comment: CarList collection does not change but it is from a file.  So, once form loads, CarList collection is loaded from a file and used by the ComboBox to allow user to select a Car.  So, it does not change really but it has to come from a file.  Would CoverterParameter still be an option and how to add it?  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, a common practice of using `ComboBox` is as below:

**In the ViewModel**

- Define collection as a property in your VM (as you did for
  `CarsList`)
- Define selected item as a property in your VM (use
  another property e.g.: `SelectedCar`)

**In the View**

- Bind `ItemsSource` to the 'collection' property.
- Bind `SelectedItem` to the 'selected item' property.

e.g.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CarsList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
</ComboBox>
```

If you want to set a default item for selection, you just set `SelectedCar` property to that item. And when user changed the selection, you will be able to always get the selected item from `SelectedCar` property.

***Edit: Simple working example:***

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel()
            {
                CarsList = new ObservableCollection<Car>() 
                { 
                    new Car() { Name = "Car1" }, 
                    new Car() { Name = "Car2" }, 
                    new Car() { Name = "Car3" }, 
                    new Car() { Name = "Car4" } 
                }
            };
            this.DataContext = mvm;
        }
    }

    public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private Car _selectedcar;
        public ObservableCollection<Car> CarsList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Car SelectedCar
        {
            get { return _selectedcar; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedcar)
                {
                    _selectedcar = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCar");
                }
            }
        }


    }

    public class Car : ObservableObject
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _name)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {                
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CarsList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedCar.Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Result: The text in `TextBlock` will update when the select of `ComboBox` changed.

[image: Text in TextBlock updated when user select from ComboBox]

Comment: Would you mind elaborating bit more.  Do you have any good example of ComboBox being used this way?  Much appreciated

Comment: Much appreciated Bolu.  That is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the ComboBox's SelectionChanged event to update the IsSelected property of each item in your bound list, setting only the new selection to 'True', and all others to 'False'.

This means you won't need a converter, which @bars222 pointed out is currently not properly returning the type of enumerable that you're binding to.

Note that this won't allow the ComboBox to update the selected item when you set an item's 'IsSelected' property to 'True' - but you should be making those changes by binding the combox's SelectedItem directly to a public SelectedCar property on ViewModel.  When the view-model loads, you can initialize this SelectedCar by inspecting the list, and the appropriate item will be shown as selected.

Comment: I am trying to figure out why is the converter not returning proper value.  Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you would like to apply MVVM patterns to your design.
I would suggest that you dont need a converter, you can manage your collection in your view model.